# Is a C-style enum typedef in C++11 invalid in some cases?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Am I just having a stupid typo I can't find? Or why do I get for this `typedef`:

```
typedef enum ErrorCode_e
{
    NO_ERROR,
    GENERAL_ERROR,
    UNINITIALIZED_DATA_ACCESS,
    ALLOCATION_ERROR,
    READ_WRITE_ERROR,
    NO_FILESTREAM
} ErrorCode_t;
```

this error:

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 NO_ERROR,
 ^
```

If it is not a typo, I'm pretty sure I did this many times in C so is it really different in C++?

I'm explicitly compiling as C++11 if that matters.

Comment: You probably have a `#define NO_ERROR /* something */`.

Comment: [Looks fine to me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb59a20a8ccc8ec7). There's almost no reason to do this in C++ though.

Comment: @T.C. you should post that as answer! Probably its a define of qt. after i changed for testing `NO_ERROR` to `NO_ERROR_BLAH` it compiled. But I checked it and made sure MY code doesn't define it.

Comment: @Zaibis a good IDE would take you to the definition of `NO_ERROR` ...

Comment: Is there any reason to use typedef?

Comment: You can also do only the preprocessing step, then check for `NO_ERROR`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I was thinking the same. But its not my decission to use qt ;)